# Is it normal to have a slightly open throttle-plate?

Tags: vw, throttle, passat, throttle-body, manifold-absolute-pressure-sensor

Recently I had experienced a Check Engine on  2012 VolksWagen Passat, and the error code was P0106.
After quick research I found that I can replace the `Map Sensor` as well as the `PCV Valve`. Both together were about $50 or $60 in the local autopart store.

During the Map Sensor replacement process, I removed the Throttle Body and cleaned it with brake cleaner spray. However, I did notice that the throttle plate does not close/snap all the bad to a perfect fit. Also, I noticed a whole lot of black (grease?) that could potentially be a long term accumulation of air (similar to how the black carbon accumulated in the throttle body and plate?).

I am wondering, as the throttle plate is spring loaded, and does not close/snap all the way, does the on-board computer align the closure for a good seal? Or does it have to be done manually by the OBDII?

In one of the replacement YouTube [videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4nYqqIAloP0&t=3s), the good fella did use `VCDS` to adapt the throttle body. I do not have VCDS and only have three cheap OBDII dongles ([Carista](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00YVHGTBM), [Autel AutoLink AL319](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B007XE8C74), [Foseal](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00W0SDLRY)), but I do not believe they can adapt the throttle body.

Question is, after the Map Sensor and PVC Valve repalcement - the car is driving just fine, and the error has not come back yet. But is it alright to have the spring-loaded throttle body not close all the way? Also, any recommendation to a DIY to align the throttle body? Or make sure that the throttle-plate closes properly?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Not sure on your Passat, but if a throttle body doesn't have a idle air control (IAC) valve, air has to get in somewhere to allow it to idle.

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen a throttle plate that closes completely, but then I've never specifically looked for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most if not all butterflies on throttle bodies do not close all the way. It stays open to a predetermined gap. The IAC further regulates how much air to increase or decrease as needed to maintain preferred idle.